# Global var in Alloy.js

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have an older app with Appcelerator Titanium SDK 5.0 and i need put in Titanium SDK 7.5. This app run in Android.

In Alloy.js file is defined several var, then i need use it in several .js files

Alloy.js

```
var Temperaturas[];
var Confort;
```

Index.js

```
Alloy.Globals.Temperaturas[0]=25;
Alloy.Globals.Temperaturas[1]=23;
Alloy.Globals.Confort=21;
```

Programacion.js

```
Alloy.Globals.Temperaturas[0]=27;
Alloy.Globals.Temperaturas[1]=27;
Alloy.Globals.Confort=22;
```

The problem is var Confort run fine, but Temperaturas don't

How i can do it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use var on alloy.js.

Change `var Temperaturas[]` by `Alloy.Globals.Temperaturas = []` on alloy.js